# Hardware RAID 10 for dual-boot system

Tags: windows, linux, multi-boot, raid

I'm considering setting up a dual boot configuration with a RAID 10 setup , provided by the [motherboard - Gigabyte GA-EP35-DS4](http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Products/Motherboard/Products_Overview.aspx?ProductID=2744).

Will there be any issues with set up considering that I plan on dual-booting Linux and Windows XP with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These desktop motherboards provide software RAID. This means that they make possible to boot the RAID volume, but after that a driver does the work. The OS has to support the specific RAID application.

**Booting** from such a software RAID volume **is** at least **tricky under Linux**. **Windows isn't a big issue** since you've got drivers with your motherboard.

However, if you use software RAID you can't use hibernation.

All in all, if you can install Linux to the volume then I say you're good to go. Maybe the Linux bootloader will mess things up, but I doubt it.